# Searching for strings in a 'dictionary' file with multiple wildcard values

Tags: string, python-3.x, wildcard

I am trying to create a function which will take 2 parameters. A word with wildcards in it like "*arn*val" and a file name containing a dictionary. It returns a list of all words that match the word like ["carnival"].

My code works fine for anything with only one "*" in it, however any more and I'm stumped as to how to do it.

Just searching for the wildcard string in the file was returning nothing.

Here is my code:

```
dictionary_file = open(dictionary_filename, 'r')
dictionary = dictionary_file.read()
dictionary_file.close()
dictionary = dictionary.split()

alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
            "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
            "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

new_list = []

for letter in alphabet:
    if wildcard.replace("*", letter) in dictionary:
        new_list += [wildcard.replace("*", letter)]

return new_list
```

The parameters parameters: First is the wildcard string (wildcard), and second is the dictionary file name (dictionary_filename).

Most answers on this site were about Regex, which I have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular error is that `.replace` replaces all occurrences e.g., `"*arn*val"` -> `"CarnCval"` or `"IarnIval"`. You want different letters here. You could use the second nested loop over the alphabet (or use `itertools.product()` to generate all possible letter pairs) to fix it but a simpler way is to use regular expressions:

```
import re

# each `*` corresponds to an ascii lowercase letter
pattern = re.escape(wildcard).replace("\\*", "[a-z]")
matches = list(filter(re.compile(pattern+"$").match, known_words))
```

Note: it doesn't support escaping `*` in the `wildcard`.

If input wildcards are file patterns then you could use [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) to filter words:

```
import fnmatch

matches = fnmatch.filter(known_words, wildcard)
```

Comment: Thank you, the code is working great now. I feel like Regular Expressions are something I'm going to have to go look into now so I can really understand this properly.